# How to solve this error"Malformed URL"?

Tags: extjs, urldecode, extjs3

I want to pass a params string include style Tag like example:

```
       a:"<font color=blue>testing!@#$%^&*()_+{}|:"<>?-=[]\;',./"
```

i am using decodeURI to pass the string.but still got error in extjs.

I has been checked,is  a symbol % cause this error come out.

How to solve it??

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that I understand your question completely, but you should probably start by escaping your string to prevent the second `"` from terminating your string.

```
// Original:
a:"<font color=blue>testing!@#$%^&*()_+{}|:"<>?-=[]\;',./"
```

You can tell by the syntax highlighting that the original string is terminated premature.

```
// Escaped:
a:"<font color=blue>testing!@#$%^&*()_+{}|:\"<>?-=[]\\;',./"
```

By using the escape character `\` you can tell JS to interpret the second `"` as part of the string, and not a string terminator. You should also escape the `\` character near the end of your string to prevent JS thinking you are using it to escape the `;` character.

Answer (score 0):

1)Ext.getCmp('txt').setValue(Ext.util.Format.htmlDecode(getSel.data.Message));

use Ext.util.Format.htmlDecode

2nd part is
params: {
                           msg: (Ext.getCmp('txt').getValue())

no need to encode

3)

Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Msg.aspx.cs" Inherits="Msg" ValidateRequest="false" %>

open Msg.aspx
add in ValidateRequest="false"